# Как сохранить значения UnityEvent?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor, serializedobject

Проблема в следующем. У меня есть объект от `MonoBehaviour`, в котором определены несколько `UnityEvent`.

```
public class PovEvents : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool UseEnter = false;
    [SerializeField]
    public UnityEvent EnterToPoV;
}
```

Мне хочется обращаться к этому обработчику в редакторе из объекта который имеет список таких объектов. В классе наследнике от Editor я отрисовываю объект со списком `PovEvents`. Внутри  получаю доступ к ссылке на `PovEvents` и если крыжик у события включен я отрисовываю его так

```
private void drawEvntTable(Rect r, PovEvents pov, string evnt)
{
    EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
    SerializedObject so = new SerializedObject(pov);
    SerializedProperty p = so.FindProperty(evnt);
    EditorGUI.PropertyField(r, p, (GUIContent)null, true);
    if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
    {
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(pov);
        //so.ApplyModifiedProperties() ;
        //so.UpdateIfRequiredOrScript();
    }
}
```

Все рисуется, все замечательно, за исключением одного но: Когда я добавляю обработчик и настраиваю чтобы в некоем объекте через `GameObject.SetActive()` устанавливалось `true`,
[image: Стандартный обработчик UnityEvent в редакторе]

то после того как я ухожу с объекта и опять к нему возвращаюсь я вижу что галочка с `true` сбрасывается на `false`. Пробовал и другие варианты обновления объекта, они закоменчены, тоже не помогает.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать? :-B

Comment: может дело  в том, что если галку поставить, то перерисовка окна не триггерится и поэтому SetDirty не срабатывает? Попробуй в редакторе записывать данные при изменении гуя будет что-то типа такого `public void OnGUI() { if (GUI.changed) {
    Undo.RecordObject(scriptableObj, "Test Scriptable Editor Modify"); 

    EditorUtility.SetDirty(scriptableObj); 
} }` ... возможно как-то переделаешь под себя....еще замечу, что `SetDirty` начиная с *Unity > 5.3*  является устаревшей и нужно использовать именно `ApplyModifiedProperties` причем как я понимаю в связке с `so.Update()`

Comment: глянь https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/125699/81175 - может быть чем-то поможет

Comment: Приводи полный код, ну или подробнее опиши, что-то очень скомкано, что за обработчик? где ты пытаешься сделать 'GameObject.SetActive()' ?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ расписал и добавил картинку

Comment: @АлексейШиманский через GUI.changed изменение фиксируется, но само значение не сохраняется. Я думаю главная загвоздка в том, что я получаю ссылку на объект в сцене. и пытаюсь по ссылке в редакторе обновиться не изменяя самого объекта.